# Return value of property from object and property name

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Given an object and the name of a property, I'm trying to use reflection to get the value of that property.  I've seen several threads here that are getting me close, but I'm not nailing it just yet.  I happen to know that the value will be of type string.

```
public string GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
{
    return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(????);
}
```

Comment: That thread is one that I looked at carefully.  But in that example, the method is returning an object, and not a string which would be the value of propName.  I'm trying to modify that example just a little.

Comment: Sorry, but it really is duplicate. You can adjust the answer from the related question for your needs. You can convert the returned `object` to `string` the same way as you would do that for regular `object` variable, thus that part has nothing in common with reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the `src` object like this:

```
public string GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
{
    return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null).ToString();
}
```